# Extra symbol during citation processin with WileyNJD-v2[AMA,STIX1COL] template

Tags: pdftex, citing

I am trying to generate a pdf from the following `LaTeX` document:

**Main.tex**

```
    \documentclass[AMA,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}
    \usepackage[english]{babel} 
    \begin{document} 

    \cite{cite0001}. 

    \bibliography{Bibliography} 

    \end{document}
```

and **Bibliography.bib**:

```
    @article{cite0001,
      title={Analysis of non-orthogonal multiple access for 5G},
      author={Wang, Yingmin and Ren, Bin and Sun, Shaohui and Kang, Shaoli and Yue, Xinwei},
      journal={China Communications},
      volume={13},
      number={2},
      pages={52--66},
      year={2016},
      publisher={IEEE}
    }
```

I execute pdflatex and bibtex with the commands:

1. pdflatex Main.tex // to generate init Main.aux
2. bibtex Main       // to generate Main.bbl
3. pdflatex Main.tex // to generate Main.aux with bibitems
4. pdflatex Main.tex // to generate final pdf

The three first steps are completed successfully. But the forth step causes the error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...e ,\NAT@spacechar \fi \NAT@@close }}
                                                  
l.26 ...on text and some citation: \cite{cite0001}
                                                  .
? 
! Emergency stop.
<argument> ...e ,\NAT@spacechar \fi \NAT@@close }}
                                                  
l.26 ...on text and some citation: \cite{cite0001}
                                                  .
End of file on the terminal!
```

It works fine for other styles, for example, `\documentclass[AMS,STIX1COL]{WileyNJD-v2}`

Comment: where exactly does one get that `WileyNJD-v2` class?

Comment: You can find here: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/pb-assets/assets/14678640/AMA-stix-1521468608820.zip

Comment: Please update your question with this important information

Comment: You can cut your example down to `\documentclass[AMA]{WileyNJD-v2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\cite{cite0001}.
\bibliography{Bibliography}
\end{document}
`

Comment: Not sure why `babel` is relevant

Comment: My guess is that badly renamed copy of `natbib` that it is using. If you rename `NJDnatbib.sty` (copy of a natbib from 2010) then it will use `natbib` from the system instead and that compiles fine for me

Comment: You might want to send the publisher an email and get them to update their stuff.

Comment: daleif, I cannot  rename NJDnatbib.sty. I should use it in my document.

Comment: If you look in the cls it automatically loads natbib I NJDnatbib is not found. So it is build to work without it.

Comment: Thank you a lot, @daleif, I will contact with publisher.

Comment: If you look in `NJDnatbib.sty` you'll see that they just renamed the package but never bothered to rename the error messsages, so they still (wrongly) mention `natbib`. IMO this is sloppy work that the publisher should fix.